Node.js Unexpected Keyword and Block-scoped error : I keep getting these errors in Ln 1, Ln 5, Ln 16. What am I doing wrong?
Ln 1 error is "unexpected keyword or identifier" for 5 words
Ln 5 error is "Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'reservationSchema'."
Ln 16 error is "Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Reservation'."
1. npm install express mongoose cors dotenv

3. server/models/Reservation.js
4. const mongoose = require('mongoose');
5. const reservationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
6. customerName: String,
7. email: String,
8. phone: String,
9. restaurant: String,
10. date: Date,
11. time: String,
12. guests: Number,
13. status: { type: String, default: 'pending' }, // pending, confirmed, canceled
14. createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
15. });
16. const Reservation = mongoose.model('Reservation', reservationSchema);
17. module.exports = Reservation;
18. server/routes/admin.js
19. const express = require('express');


Are you saying that the first line of your source file is npm install express mongoose cors dotenv? If so, that seems very wrong to me. I suspect the intention is that you run that from a shell first. Next, the second line looks like "server/models/Reservation.js" - again, is that in your source file? That should be the name of a file, not a line in a file... (Fundamentally, it's unclear what all these numbered lines are intended to be...)
